# PMP certification experience hours for each PM phase

Tags: pmp

I am filling out my application for PMP cert, but a very small percentage of my hours are allocated to the 'Initial' phase. Would this a deal-breaker?

Comment: Only PMI can answer questions about how PMI interprets the application. The answer you get here will not be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the application's first and foremost tracking is "do you have the hours required." The detailed breakdown just give more information to them and you (shows you where you probably need to study more).